# How can tests reference external resources in a parent source directory in a TFS 2012 build?

Tags: c#, mstest, tfsbuild

I'm setting up a TFS 2012 build agent and have run into a small problem with unit tests that reference external files. (Yes, yes, this is bad...no arguments there! I still have to get a build running) The tests are using the MSTest (VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting) framework.

Currently, there is a `Resources` folder under the solution root, and all the tests (which are unfortunately at varying depths in subdirectories) load files with some level of relative paths (`..\\..\\..\\Resources\\resource.txt`).

TFS, as you know, copies **all** output to a `bin` folder that is at the same level as `src`, which has the required `Resources` folder. There is no way to copy this folder high up enough in the directory structure so the tests pass for the build agent.

I am hoping that either of these questions can give me a stop-gap solution to this problem:

1. Is there any environment variable (or something similar) that I could use to detect that the unit test is being run through a TFS build agent and change the path to the resource file in code accordingly?
2. Is there a simple way to tell TFS to output files into the `bin` folder with the same hierarchy as they would have normally been if built in Visual Studio? (The reason I say *simple* is because I've found some rather long build modifications that could probably handle this)

Answer (score 3):

Option1: Yes, you can copy a folder and it's contents to the \bin\Debug folder:

1. Add a folder to your test project
2. Add your files in that folder and in Visual Studio set each file property "Copy to Output Directory" : "Copy Always"

Option 2: You can also put your file into a resource file

Option 3: or declare the file it in your test using the attribute:

```
[TestMethod]
[DeploymentItem("mytestdata.xml")]
```

Comment: Option 1: Unfortunately we don't want to make duplicate copies of these external resource files (some are 300MB) because several different test assemblies use them.

Comment: Option 2: Perhaps an option, but that would require changing a lot of existing test code.

Comment: Option 3 might hold some promise :) I'm going to investigate further.

Comment: I've been testing it Option 3 more and it seems to have some odd characteristics for relative parent paths between running locally and on a build controller